# How to calculate CR2032 battery life with LED

Tags: power, batteries, coin-cell

I want to power an LED that has a 3.3V forward voltage using two 3V CR2032 coin cell batteries to create a 6V supply. I set the resistor for a 20 mA current. For my application, the LED will be turned on for about five minutes a day.

The CR2032 has a capacity of 235 mAh (Energizer datasheet: http://data.energizer.com/pdfs/cr2032.pdf)
The datasheet only has a "continuous discharge characteristics" curve for a 0.19 mA drain.

How do I know what the capacity is at the current draw level of 20 mA? How can I estimate the battery life, besides dividing the mAh capacity by the current draw?

It's confusing because on some sites I've read that coin cell capacity seriously degrades if you continuously draw more than a few mA... but I've seen many keychain LED flashlights that even use the smaller capacity CR2016 battery.

Comment: Note that because of how different your voltages are (~3.3V and 4-6V), your series resistor will waste a considerable amount of power.  The internal resistance of your battery ranges from 10 to 140 ohms and they're rated for pulses of 1/3 the current you want to run, so they probably won't do well with 3 times that current continuously.

Comment: With a Red or Yellow  you only get about 150mAh out of possible 225 mAh or about 1/2 day bright, 1/2 less bright , 2 days very dim.  With White a bit less. This directly across CR2032  Current is limited by internal ESR then by voltage drop below Vf of White LED of  3V down to 2.8V But white is not using 20mA., perhaps 5mA depending on part.  Because brightness, LED voltage and battery voltage are very dynamic, and lifespan in seconds is hard to model without a well defined test procedure and cutoff.

Comment: See the application manual http://data.energizer.com/pdfs/lithiumcoin_appman.pdf for 3mA curve.

Comment: Tony's comment should be an answer. For once.

Comment: Ok thanks for the advice, I'll have to see how bright the LED is with a smaller current like 5 mA...or go for the bigger CR2477 coin cell! It seems like there's no obvious answer here...

Comment: Your options are: Use a higher capacity battery, reduce your load and/or improve efficiency

Comment: Coin cells are an expensive battery for the charge they deliver.  If you just want a compact battery, you could consider a phone battery or try to get a secondhand tablet battery.  Excessive for the purpose, but you may be able to get one cheaply by salvaging from unused electronics.  You can get a cheap generic lithium ion charge from USB board to charge it too if you want.  I think some coin cells because of the chemicals involved, are either incredibly wasteful or bad for the environment if they are being switched out often, so consider many battery types if it's an option.

Comment: @Oliver That's very succinct.  He's right.  I'd go for higher capacity battery and improve efficiency, and depending on the higher capacity battery, maybe you want a brighter light, not a dimmer one =)

Comment: If you can get a salvaged tablet battery, you could hide mega storage capacity in the lid or bottom of the box.  Some of them are large flat plates as thin as 2.5 to 3mm.

Comment: Just one question: what does "improve efficiency" entail? The only options I see besides a higher capacity battery are increasing the LED resistor value for less current draw (if the LED is still bright enough) or finding a brighter LED...

Answer (score 2):

You can only rely on the (Amp Hour) the battery has. Or for small batteries the mAh (milli amp hour). Anyway all these figures are estimates anyway. The lifetimes depends e.g. on temperature.

I don't know what you need the LED for but you can get LEDs which are a lot more efficient: 1 mA would give you 20x as long.

As K H said: you are wasting energy in a series resistor: Try to find a switching current source. A simple PWM circuit with an inductor comes to mind.

Comment: I need the LED to illuminate a box. This isn't just an indicator LED, so I don't think 1 mA would be sufficient.

Comment: Also, are you referring to PWM for the purpose of dimming the LED?

Comment: @donut you'd be surprised how bright a led is at 1mA especially at night/dark. Depends on the size of the box tho. Try 5mA.

Comment: With PWM I am thinking of some sort of unregulated switching current supply. Combined with an L you can save a lot of energy. (Note that LEDs are controlled by current, not voltage).

Comment: LEDs also are more efficient at lower instantaneous voltages, meaning that if you Give an LED a 10V square wave with 32% duty cycle, it will have an effective voltage of 3.2V and the LED probably won't burn out, but if you increase the frequency of the square wave and run it through an inductor as @oldfart is describing, you can have the efficiency of switched mode and constant voltage output similar to a linear supply.

Comment: You can also use PWM to dim an LED below it's turn-off voltage, but that is a separate purpose.  My current hobby project is designing a modular LED driver system that can control both instantaneous voltage for the LEDS as well as the 0-100% square wave at that voltage to drive them.